# How to get inputs in a given time frame?

Tags: python, neural-network, raspberry-pi

I'm doing a project where the inputs are taken from wheel encoder in the form of float values. How to get input for every 60 seconds and feed the inputs to the neural network model.
In the code km_per_hour has to recorded for every 60 seconds and fed to neural network.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_GPIO()
    init_interrupt()
    while True:
        calculate_speed(40)
        print('kmh:{1:.0f}'.format(km_per_hour))
        sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the time at the start of each round and check if 60s have passed.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    init_GPIO()
    init_interrupt()
    while True:
        start_time = time.time()  # seconds since unix time
        end_time = start_time + 60
        list_speeds = list()
        while time.time() < end_time:
            km_per_hour = calculate_speed(40)
            list_speeds.append(km_per_hour)
            print('kmh:{1:.0f}'.format(km_per_hour))
            sleep(0.1)
        else:  # while-else
            feed_your_dino(list_speeds)
```

If you don't want to lock your inputs, you can do the following, to run it the function in a new thread, not locking your program:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time, threading
    init_GPIO()
    init_interrupt()
    while True:
        start_time = time.time()  # seconds since unix time
        end_time = start_time + 60
        list_speeds = list()
        while time.time() < end_time:
            km_per_hour = calculate_speed(40)
            list_speeds.append(km_per_hour)
            print('kmh:{1:.0f}'.format(km_per_hour))
            sleep(0.1)
        else:  # while-else
            th_my_ai = threading.Thread(target=feed_your_dino, args=(list_speeds,))
            th_my_ai.start()
```